# Static variables and Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been migrating my application to Amazon's web services, and one thing that confuses me is what happens to my static variables? Do they persist across instances (and if not, how do I persist them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, static variables in your applications that run on multiple EC2 instances do *not* persist across instances.

Your two options will either be a database, such as [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) or [Dynamo](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb), or an in-memory solution that supports same region replication like [ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/).

When thinking of the cloud, the important thing to remember when dealing with an application that can scale is volatility. Instead of having a single server that lives for the entire duration of the application, it is more useful to think of instances as that can be killed off and spawned at any time. Thus relying on in memory state is very dangerous.

Comment: Can a complex variable be "stored" in RDS or Dynamo? E.g. as a session variable, or will my application have to serialize data?

Comment: It depends on how complex it is. Do you have an example of what kind of object you might be thinking of? Also this ServerFault answer might be enlightening: http://serverfault.com/a/32453

Comment: It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/wtEXSM3A That ServerFault answer was indeed enlightening. I'm new to cloud computing, but I'm leaning towards the database option so if my application happens to run out of memory on one instance (because there are a lot of in-memory operations like file processing), I guess the application can "gracefully" recover on another instance, right? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Cool. Since your object doesn't seem to have other methods besides getters and setters, it would seem easier to do the last option: store your `Order` object in the database, associate a session with a session ID stored in the user's cookie and then use that to retrieve information as it needs.

Also, become familiar with Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), it will be what you want to setup and configure for determining if an instance runs out of memory (ie, is ["unhealthy"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#healthcheck)).